# Doxygen @todo Tag

Tags: formatting, doxygen, todo

I'm having a strange issue with the `@todo` command when I have other formatted data below it in a list in the latest version of doxygen (1.8). Consider the following example:

```
/**
@page build_instructions Build Instructions
- Library1
    - @todo Detail build process

    - get source
    - build release/debug version for x64
    - build release/debug version for x86
*/
```

If you run it, you will notice that the `@todo` tag adds extra indentation to the last two list items (after "get source"). If you remove the `@todo` tag, then the indentation looks OK. Also, if I remove the `-` in front of `@todo`, it encloses the items below it in a box.

Is this a bug? How can I make the `@todo` tag affect only one line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm this: your code works in 1.5 but not 1.8, so it seems like a bug. Two possible workarounds follow:

- try putting the `todo` item as the last element in the list,
- if you want the `todo` item at the top (or anywhere other than the last element) in the list, then try putting a blank line in between each of the list items which follow the `todo` item.